# php use which tools to generate document

Tags: php, document

all. I view the php source code ,and found it souce code comment use this style

```
    /* {{{ proto resource pfsockopen(string hostname, int port [, int errno [, string errstr [, float timeout]]])
   Open persistent Internet or Unix domain socket connection */
PHP_FUNCTION(pfsockopen)
{
        php_fsockopen_stream(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU, 1);
}
/* }}} */
```

I am interesting about this, does somebody can tell me ? thx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{{ }}} are most likely used as folding markers in vim(though maybe other editor also offer a possibility to mark folds with such symbols.). If these are what made you wonder.

Edit:
Comment does not seem to be suitable for documentation generation since it seems to be quite unstructured/free form. If its php source code and is written in C(i guess here) it most likely would be using doxygen for generating documents, while php programs themselves use phpdoc. Maybe this is some custom/edited version of php source?

Comment: understand your mean. It looks like php use some tools generate document use this string, you can see it http://au.php.net/fsockopen , Description chapter . I only know the doxygen can generate code ,but looks like not this style. PHP use which tools ? private tools?